# Why my Android FTP server is faster than on PC?

Tags: windows, ftp, android, .net-framework

I am programming a little program in C#, and I am testing it with uploading a file to FTP server, on my Android phone I am using [Ulti Server app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.ultiserver) and on my PC (Windows 8.1 x64) I am using [Xlight FTP Server](http://www.xlightftpd.com/).

Both of them are accessed via external IP address.

Now, the problem is when I am pushing a file to the Android FTP server (connected to internet via Wi-Fi), it takes like 350ms, but on the PC FTP server (wired connected to the same internet router), it takes like 1400ms, both with the same file.

Why is that? Do I need to provide some additional info?

EDIT: here's the code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
client.UploadFile("ftp://78.80.194.121:8080/pu.rtf", @"C:\pu.rtf");
```

Comment: Sounds like a code optimization problem.

Comment: no, the code is just 3 lines...

Comment: 3 lines to implement what you implemented does not compute.

Comment: there, I added the code

Comment: Does the speed difference remain if you use a larger test file?  Perhaps, try a different FTP server on the PC (like Filezilla) and see if the times are any different when compared to Xlight.

Comment: give me link for Filezilla please, for installation without the bloatware that comes with it from the official site

Comment: I can already tell you that `WebClient` is great for small files but won't work for larger files.  You would need to implement a proper multi-thread FTP functionality to compare Apples to Apples.